# How to implement theming via dynamically loaded ResourceDictionary?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I'm working on conditionally loading a `ResourceDictionary` basing on which theme is currently selected. Say, that I have the following:

[Theme-Dark.xaml]

```xml
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    
    <!-- Colors -->
    
    <Color x:Key="Dark1Color">#1b2936</Color>

    <!-- ... -->
    
    <!-- Brushes -->
    
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="TextboxNormalBackgroundBrush" Color="{StaticResource Dark1Color}" />

    <!-- ... -->

</ResourceDictionary>
```

[Styles.xaml]

```xml
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    
    <!-- Styles -->
    
    <Style TargetType="TextBox">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource TextboxNormalBackgroundBrush}" />
    </Style>

</ResourceDictionary>
```

If I add `Theme-Dark.xaml` to `Styles.xaml`'s MergedDictionaries directly in xaml, **everything works properly** (so this is not a case of typos etc.). However, I would like to be able to load theme file with colors conditionally, basing on current application's theme. So I wrote the following code:

```cs
ResourceDictionary themeDictionary = new ResourceDictionary();
themeDictionary.Source = new Uri("/MyApp;component/Wpf/Theme-Dark.xaml", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);

ResourceDictionary styleDictionary = new ResourceDictionary();
styleDictionary.Source = new Uri("/MyApp;component/Wpf/Styles.xaml", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
styleDictionary.MergedDictionaries.Add(themeDictionary);

_content.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add(styleDictionary);

ehWpfContent.Child = _content;
```

Upon opening the form containing `ElementHost`, which contains the control I want to style, I'm getting an exception:

```
System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException: 'Provide value on 'System.Windows.Markup.StaticResourceHolder' threw an exception.' Line number '10' and line position '55'. ---> System.Exception: Cannot find resource named 'TextboxNormalBackgroundBrush'. Resource names are case sensitive.
   at System.Windows.StaticResourceExtension.ProvideValueInternal(IServiceProvider serviceProvider, Boolean allowDeferredReference)
   at MS.Internal.Xaml.Runtime.ClrObjectRuntime.CallProvideValue(MarkupExtension me, IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
```

How can I properly add `ResourceDictionary` to `MergedDictionaries`, so that those resources will be recognized?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, read [thatguy's fantastic answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68465533/453803). It proposes first solution to this problem. I however in the meantime found two more, and it turned out, that they suited me better than using `DynamicResource`. The reason is that they are as performant as `StaticResource`, but don't share its shortcomings.

There's a pre-requirement to both solutions: **you have to load proper theme resources in a form of ResourceDictionary prior to loading any XAML, which uses it**.

This may look like following:

```cs
  public static class ThemeResourceRepository
  {
    private static readonly Uri darkThemeResourcesUri = new Uri("/MyAssembly;component/Wpf/Theme-Dark.xaml", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
    private static readonly Uri lightThemeResourcesUri = new Uri("/MyAssembly;component/Wpf/Theme-Light.xaml", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);

    private static readonly Lazy<ResourceDictionary> darkThemeResources = new Lazy<ResourceDictionary>(() => LoadResources(darkThemeResourcesUri));
    private static readonly Lazy<ResourceDictionary> lightThemeResources = new Lazy<ResourceDictionary>(() => LoadResources(lightThemeResourcesUri));

    private static ResourceDictionary LoadResources(Uri uri)
    {
      ResourceDictionary result = new ResourceDictionary();
      result.Source = uri;
      return result;
    }

    public static ResourceDictionary GetThemeResources()
    {
      switch (SomeConfigurationClass.CurrentSkin)
      {
        case Skins.Dark:
          return darkThemeResources.Value;
        case Skins.Light:
          return lightThemeResources.Value;
        default:
          throw new InvalidEnumArgumentException("Unsupported color theme!");
      }
    }
  }
```

And then:

### Solution 1: Write custom MarkupExtension

Implement a simple markup extension, like the following:

```cs
public class ThemeResource : MarkupExtension
{
    private readonly object key;

    public ThemeResource(string key)
    {
        this.key = key;
    }
 
    public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        var dictionary = ThemeResourceRepository.GetThemeResources();
        return dictionary[key];
    }
}
```

Then you can use it simply like:

```xml
<TextBlock Text="{c:ThemeResource SomeResourceKey}" />
```

Or even simpler:

### Solution 2: Derive from `ResourceDictionary`

Implement custom `ResourceDictionary` as following:

```cs
public class ThemeResourceDictionary : ResourceDictionary
{
  public ThemeResourceDictionary()
  {
    MergedDictionaries.Add(ThemeResourceRepository.GetThemeResources());
  }
}
```

Then include it in your XAML:

```xml
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                    xmlns:wpf="clr-namespace:MyAssembly.MyNamespace">

    <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        <wpf:ThemeResourceDictionary />
    </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>

    <!-- ... -->

</ResourceDictionary>
```

Important observation is that this `ResourceDictionary **will be read properly** during loading of XAML. Therefore, you may safely use` {StaticResource}` afterwards and it will just work.

Answer (score 1):

There are two different kinds of markup extensions for retrieving resources.

> A resource can be referenced as either *static* or *dynamic*. References are created by using either the `StaticResource` Markup Extension or the `DynamicResource` Markup Extension. A markup extension is a XAML feature that lets you specify an object reference by having the markup extension process the attribute string and return the object to a XAML loader.

The `StaticResource` markup extension as its name might imply has a load-time lookup behavior.

> Lookup behavior for that resource is analogous to load-time lookup, which will look for resources that were previously loaded from the markup of the current XAML page as well as other application sources, and will generate that resource value as the property value in the run-time objects.

> Processing happens during load, which is **when the loading process needs to assign the property value**.

In your case the `TextboxNormalBackgroundBrush` is used in the `Styles.xaml` dictionary.

> If I add `Theme-Dark.xaml` to `Styles.xaml`'s MergedDictionaries directly in xaml, everything works properly (so this is not a case of typos etc.).

In this case, the resources (including the brush) are instantiated and included, **before** the controls and resources in the `Styles.xaml` dictionary, e.g. `TextBox`, are created and loaded. This means, the brush is available when `StaticResource` is being resolved.

On the opposite, in your runtime resource dictionary switching code, the `Styles.xaml` dictionary is instantiated (and its contained resources, too), but at that point the `Theme-Dark.xaml` resource dictionary is not merged anywhere, therefore the `StaticResource` cannot resolve any of its resources. When `Theme-Dark.xaml` is merged, the `TextBox` in `Styles.xaml` is already created and loaded or the parser threw an exception before reaching this line.

In order to solve this problem, use the `DynamicResource` markup extension instead.

> `DynamicResource` Markup Extension instead processes a key by creating an expression, and that expression remains unevaluated until the app runs, at which time the expression is evaluated to provide a value.

This enables refering to resource that may be available later in time or are exchanged at runtime.

```
<Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource TextboxNormalBackgroundBrush}" /
```

Comment: Thank you for a very complete answer. There is one other solution though, which combines  performance of `StaticResource` and ability to reach arbitrary resource: custom markup extension. Since I have required `ResourceDictionary`, I may simply implement a markup extension, which will ignore regular searches through visual hierarchy/loaded XAMLs and get required resource directly from the proper place.

Comment: So I came up with one more solution, even better than one mentioned in previous comment. One may create a new class, `ThemeResourceDictionary`, which in ctor loads appropriate `ResourceDictionary` into its `MergedResources`. Then you may simply merge it in XAML and all resources of theme dictionary will be fully available through regular `{StaticResource}`!